# Listing Snowflake shares outside of the ACCOUNTADMIN role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to list all outbound shares in my Snowflake account. I'm aware that I can use

```
show shares;
```

But per the [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-shares.html), "Executing this command using any role other than `ACCOUNTADMIN` returns empty results." I'd like to retrieve the list of shares from a less privileged role than `ACCOUNTADMIN`. How can I do this?

Note, in my case I don't have the option of setting up a job that runs as `ACCOUNTADMIN` to export the data from `show shares` to another table.

Answer (score 0):

You may grant IMPORT SHARE privilege to a non-accountadmin role, any user with the role can perform the following tasks:

- View all INBOUND shares (shared by provider accounts) and create databases for the shares.
- View all OUTBOUND shares owned by the role.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-privileges-shares.html#enabling-non-accountadmin-roles-to-perform-data-sharing-tasks

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for me. I need to get the list of all outbound shares in the account owned by any role. I've updated the question to clarify that I need outbound shares specifically.

Comment: Listing of shares owned by any role can only be achieved by using the role Accountadmin.